# Trying to create a function nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Im trying to create a function so i dont use the same code again and again but i keep getting internal error.I get the data and then i get the internal error so if i change something i need to refresh the page to be updated.I cant understand why i get the error.Here is the error

GET http://localhost:3000/api/pages 500 (Internal Server Error)

Object {data: "", status: 500, config: Object, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}

code:

```
function Get(some,that,res){
   return some.find(function(err,that) {
      if (!err) {
        return res.send(that);
      } else {
        return res.send(500, err);
      }
   });    
};

router.get('/pages', sessionCheck, function() {
   Get(Page,pages,res);
});
```

UPDATE: i might doing something wrong so lets take it from the start.How can i create a function that do that so i dont reuse the same code again and again.

```
router.get('/pages',  function(request, response) {

        return Page.find(function(err, pages) {
            if (!err) {
                return response.send(pages);
            } else {
                return response.send(500, err);
            }
        });
    });
```

and here is my full code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Page= require('../models/page.js');    
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');



function Get(some,that,response){
    return some.find(function(that,err) {
        if (!err) {
            return response.send(that);
        } else {
            return response.send(500, err);
        }
    });    
};

router.get('/pages', sessionCheck, function(request,response) {
    Get(Page,pages,response);
});
```

Comment: would help to post the error

Comment: oh and in your router you're setting a function(){} with no arguments yet passing them underneath. Where do `Page,pages,res` come from.

Comment: its  variables i have define that link to Schemas.i have tried to define them inside the function but still the same.

Comment: The `router.get` function is expecting a piece of middleware to process the request. The function you pass it should take the response and request objects e.g. `router.get('/pages', sessionCheck, function(request, response) { /* ... */ });`

Comment: Page & pages also don't exist, try the above and then call `Get` with just the `response` variable. Inside your `Get` function you can then use the Page/pages vars if you have required them at the top of your file. If you post your full file it will be easier for someone to answer your question completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

router.*METHOD* will first call your function *sessionCheck*. You will then need to call next() within *sessionCheck* to call the next function, in which you are not defining any parameters (typically you would define *req, res*).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express your function call should probably be:

```
  function someGetFunc(req, res, next)
```

You have res as the third parameter, so that might be the problem.

Now the Get function you have above is internal to an anonymous function that doesn't take in params, so what you are passing into it are either undefined or reference global scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it like that i shouldnt have left the function empty it required res,req

```
function Get(Some,that,res){
    return Some.find(function(err,that) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.send(that);
        } else {
            return res.send(500, err);
        }
    });    
};

router.get('/pages', sessionCheck,function(req,res) {
    Get(Page,pages,res);
});
```